# Getting single node without knowing its namespace

Tags: c#, xml

I have to get certain nodes(their InnerText) from xml file. I know their names, but nodes might be using some namespaces which i don't know.
Is it possible to get node using SelectSingleNode() or some other method without knowing the namespace the node is using? Is it possible to ignore namespaces the nodes are using?

Answer (score 3):

Use namespace-agnostic XPath. Not particularly nice or efficient, but it works.

Instead of this:

```
/ns1:foo/ns2:bar/ns3:baz
```

use this:

```
/*[local-name() = 'foo']/*[local-name() = 'bar']/*[local-name() = 'baz']
```

Be prepared to face the consequences of losing namespaces:

```
<ns1:foo>
  <wrong:bar>
    <wrong:baz />    <!-- this would be selected (false positive) -->
  </wrong:bar>
  <ns2:bar>
    <ns3:baz />
  </ns2:bar>
</ns1:foo>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
doc.Load("foo.xml");

XmlElement b, f1, f2;

b =  (XmlElement)doc.SelectSingleNode("//bar");
f1 = (XmlElement)b.SelectSingleNode("ancestor::foo[1]");
f2 = (XmlElement)b.SelectNodes("ancestor::foo")[0];

Console.WriteLine(f1.GetAttribute("depth"));
Console.WriteLine(f2.GetAttribute("depth"));
```